# Cholesky algorithm

Tags: linear-algebra, matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, octave, cholesky-decomposition

Good afternoon everyone, I'm in need of a factoring algorithm cholesky and algorithms to solve upper and lower triangular systems, but I'm not finding any work in that octave. Recalling that need the algorithm and can not just use the already available functions in the programs.
I even tried to adapt this algorithm but it is in trouble in the windows octave

```
function [G] = cholesky(A,dim)
epsilon = 1.0e-10;
sum = 0.0;
                for k = 1:(i-1)
                sum = sum + G(k,i)*G(k,i);
                end
        delta = A(i,i) - sum;
        if( delta < 0.0 ), errorspd(delta,i); end
          G(i,i) = sqrt(delta);
         if( abs(G(i,i)) < epsilon );  end
         for j = (i+1):ndim
                        sum = 0.0;
                        for k = 1:(i-1)
                        sum = sum + G(k,i)*G(k,j);
                        end
            G(i,j) = ( A(i,j) - sum ) / G(i,i);
             end
        end
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my Matlab code for Cholesky, I hope it works also on Octave. It is taken step by step by the wikipedia [Cholesky–Banachiewicz algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#The_Cholesky.E2.80.93Banachiewicz_and_Cholesky.E2.80.93Crout_algorithms):

```
     function[L]=MyChol(A)

     [n,m]=size(A);
     L=eye(n);
     for k=1:n-1
           L(k,k)=sqrt(A(k,k));  %Computing the diagonal
           L(k+1:n,k)=(A(k+1:n,k))/L(k,k); %Computing the lower part
           A(k+1:n,k+1:n)=A(k+1:n,k+1:n)-L(k+1:n,k)*L(k+1:n,k)'; %Putting the new A for the next step on the loop
     end
     L(n,n)=sqrt(A(n,n));
     end
```

The $L$ obtained is such that $A=LL^T$. For solving upper triangular systems of the form $Ux=b$, I use the next code based on the [backward substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_and_back_substitution)

```
    function [x] = triup(U,b)

    n = length(b);
    x = zeros(n,1);

    % backward substitution
    x(n) = b(n)/U(n,n);
    for k = n-1:-1:1
        x(k) = ( b(k) -U(k,(k+1):n)*x((k+1):n))/U(k,k);
    end
    % end of backward substitution

    end
```

Meanwhile for lower ones of the form $Lx=b$, I use an algorithm base on the [forward substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix#Forward_and_back_substitution)

```
   function [x] = trilo( L,b )

   n=length(L);
   x=zeros(n,1);

   % forward substitution
   for k=1:n-1
       x(k)=b(k)/L(k,k); 
       b(k+1:n)=b(k+1:n)-x(k)*L(k+1:n,k);
   end
   x(n)=b(n)/L(n,n);
   % end of forward substitution

   end
```

As an example, if you want to solve a system $Ax=b$ where $A$ is symmetric positive definite matrix, then use

```
   L=MyChol(A);
   y=trilo(L,b);
   x=triup(L',y);
```

to obtain the solution $x$.

Comment: Can you comment a bit algorithms, and I shall know better? I tested here and it seems that they are working properly

Comment: ok, I did not put the comments since I have them in spanish. Let me edit and add something.

Comment: @askazy I´ve made an edit now. I have put a little comments on the code and also add the wikipedia's links I followed to write the code, It is all there. I hope is clearer now.